# jquery tiny scrolbar showing issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, scrollbar

I am using the following tiny scrollbar plugin http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/ to apply scroll to a div inside my body. Following is the html content:

Following is the html structure:

```
 <div id="scrollbar1">
    <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
  <ul>

    <li> 
           Rated
      4 hours ago 
    </li>

    <li> 
      Rated 
      6 hours ago 
    </li>

    <li> 
      upvoted 
      6 hours ago 
    </li>

  </ul>
  </div>
```

then the javascript looks like this:

```
$(funciton(){
$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
});
```

The fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/sk9SE/2

The trouble is i am not getting the desired effect. 
Can someone please tell me what is wrong with it?

Thanks!

Comment: can you put it on fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you haven't included your viewport or overview divs - they are needed for the scrolling

here is a fixed version:

```
<div id="scrollbar1">
<div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="overview">
      <ul>
         <li> Rated 4 hours ago </li>
         <li> Rated 2 hours ago </li>
         <li> Rated 5 hours ago </li>
         <li> Rated 44 hours ago </li>
         <li> Rated 4665 hours ago </li>
         <li> Rated 124 hours ago </li>
         <li> Rated 124 hours ago </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sk9SE/4/)**